# Index Array without Elements

Tags: julia

I have a vector

```
a = Vector(1:4)

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and I want to index it to all elements **but** the third to get

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

in `R` you could do `a[-3]`. What do you do in `Julia`?

(Eventually I want to loop through all the elements and compare each of them to the rest - maybe this is relevant.)

Comment: About your parenthesis, you can probably loop through them (without comparing any to itself) like so 
`[(a[i], a[j]) for i in eachindex(a), j in eachindex(a) if j ≠ i]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Julia syntax will be unfortunately more verbose than those of R:

```
julia> a[1:end .!== 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

Another option is to mutate a:

```
julia> deleteat!(a,3)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

If your data is within a `DataFrame` than you can get a nicer syntax:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:4);

julia> df[Not(3),:]
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 2     │
│ 3   │ 4     │
```

and when `DataFrames` is imported `Not` will also work with a `Vector`:

```
julia> a[Not(3)]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

Answer (score 8):

This use case is a common one and is covered by the [InvertedIndices.jl](https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl) package. If you install it then you can run:

```
julia> using InvertedIndices

julia> a = 1:4
1:4

julia> a[Not(3)]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

Also some packages (like DataFrames.jl) automatically load this package (so if you e.g. use DataFrames.jl you do not have to install and load InvertedIndices.jl separately).

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen

```
julia> a[1:end .≠ 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

or

```
julia> a[eachindex(a) .≠ 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 4
```

mentioned, but maybe there is a good reason?

---

**EDIT**: I was wrong, the first one is actually the same as Bogumil's first answer except `!==` has been replaced with `≠`

Comment: Super inefficient if a is large